# How to inject dependency to private constructor?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, ninject

I am working on a module in ASP.net MVC app where I have a singleton class which wants to query from database and then do some processing. I am using repository pattern where my repo is ex: IQueueProcessRepository which I would I want to inject to my singleton classes private constructor.

I am not finding a way to do that. Could someone please explain how to do this?

You could also rectify if what I am trying to do is wrong. Thanks

Comment: Singleton and dependency injection dont play well together. What you could do is instead of creating an explicit singleton, use your DI framework to inject your "singleton" object to any class requiring it, and when you register that class with your DI framework, specify it's lifetime to be a singleton.

Comment: Singletons should not be your first choice of design pattern anyway.

Comment: Better would be request scope, rather than singleton. Especially if you're interacting with a database, you really want the lifetime tied to a single request.

Comment: Thank you all for ur comments. Basically my module should be running continuously in the background and doing its job which requires querying the database also; so for this case I felt singleton is best.

Answer (score 2):

To answer your question, there is no way. by definition, private constructors are inaccessible by other classes.

If you really need it to be a singleton, bind it in Singleton scope in Ninject. then Ninject will inject your repository into the singleton automatically the first time it's requested.

If you want control over the construction of the singleton, bind using `.ToConstant(object)`.

```
var singleton = Kernel.Get<MySingleton>();
Bind<IMySingleton>().ToConstant(singleton);
```